# Why is the behavior of my code being inconsistent? There is no randomization or anything

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am trying to make a little square on my screen "jump". It was all going smoothly until I tried to add a "fallSpeed" variable that would change the speed it's falling at slowly to imitate actual gravity (yes I understand it's not the most realistic representation of gravity but I'm just trying to keep it simple.) All of a sudden with this variable in place about half the time my code will work but then half the time it will get all glitchy and freak out (yes I am aware that that will happen if you hold or spam the space bar but that's not what I'm talking about, it happens just when you press the space bar.) What could be making it so inconsistent and weird, theres no randomization of anything?

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    jump(event);
  })
  var posX = 500;
  var posY = 500;
  var fallSpeed = 3;
  function moveUp() {
    if (posY > 250) {
      posY -= 3;
      document.getElementById('player').style.marginTop = posY + "px"
      fallSpeed += 0.005;
      setTimeout(() => {moveUp();}, 1);
      }
    else {
      return true;
      }
    }
  function moveDown() {
    if (posY < 500) {
      posY += fallSpeed;
      document.getElementById('player').style.marginTop = posY + "px"
      fallSpeed += 0.02;
      setTimeout(() => {moveDown();}, 1);
    }
    else {
      fallSpeed = 3;
      return;
    }
  }
  function jump(event) {
    if (event.key === " ") {
      moveUp();
      setTimeout(() => {if (moveUp) {
        moveDown();
      }}, 399)
    }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! I needed to change the delay in the second setTimeout() because it was too short because the block fell faster now.

Comment: Consider using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of setTimeout for smooth and consistent animations.